# Audio cracks in Kali OS (virtual box)

Tags: linux, virtualbox, audio, kali-linux

Issue in **kali os** in VirtualBox. Audio cracks and distorts in random interval of time. Tried changing drivers but those 2 drivers had there own problem: **Intel HD** (video buffers and plays very slow with no sound) and **SoundBlaster** (good video but no audio). I also tried reinstalling Kali but that too didn't worked.

My host pc is: Lenovo IdeaPad s540 (Win 10 , 20gb ram, 10th gen i5-10210U, 2gb mx250 nvidia graphics card, 1 TB HDD, 250 GB SSD)

I'm new to this field of using Virtual Machines, can someone help me in this issue?

[image: screenshot of my VM]

Answer (score 0):

What version of Kali?  I am in Kali V2020.3 as a VMware Workstation guest and all is smooth.

> tried changing drivers but those 2 drivers had there own problem:
> intel hd (video buffers and plays very slow with no sound) and
> soundblaster (good video but no audio)

Where did you try installing drivers?  The guest uses Virtual Hardware and drivers should be installed in the Host Machine.

> my host pc is:lenovo ideapad s540 ( win 10 , 20gb ram, 10th gen
> i5-10210U, 2gb mx250 nvidea graphics card, 1 TB HDD , 250 gb SSD)

That should work. Keep the Kali Guest on the SSD if you can. Faster disk for the Guest machine will work much better